# Alpine Linux Docker Container with jre-8 does not have Nashorn Engine

Tags: java, docker, rhino, nashorn, alpine-linux

I have a docker image based on `FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8_server-jre_unlimited`. However, when I try

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

`scriptEngine` is `null`. I tried to get the default engine with :

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
```

and it returns `null` as well, where as since it is java8, my understanding was, it should return `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine`

Is this because jre-8 here is a lighter version for Alpine? Should I install full JDK to solve this problem?

Reference : http://blog.takipi.com/lean-mean-java-virtual-machine-making-your-docker-7x-lighter-with-alpine-linux/

Comment: Both official `java:8-jre` and `java:8-jre-alpine` images have `NashornScriptEngine`, so I see no reason in using a third-party alternative. If you need it for some reason, ask the maintainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although installing openjdk8 would solve the problem, this is not the right approach. Advantage of using Alpine is to create a minimal (size) docker image, which means it has only the minimum required Java components. This is why Scripting API (Nashorn) has being removed from the image. Therefore, if we need specific Java functionality such as Scripting API, we have to switch to a full JDK version without using Alpine, or create a custom base image similar to Alpine, but with Scripting API components (for this case).

Comment: Some time ago, a Nashorn variant was added. I.e.: `8u202b08_server-jre_nashorn`, `8u202b08_jdk_nashorn`, `8_jdk_nashorn`, `8_server-jre_nashorn`.. Though, the whole thing is deprecated recently, due to Oracle's license changes.

Answer (score 2):

[The project](https://github.com/anapsix/docker-alpine-java) maintainer explicitly removes Nashorn script engine, see [the source](https://github.com/anapsix/docker-alpine-java/blob/master/8/102b14/server-jre/unlimited/Dockerfile#L71). It would make sense to file an issue at Github and ask the maintainer what is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Image `anapsix/alpine-java` doesn’t use Alpine’s official Java package, but Oracle JDK (that is distributed only as a binary compiled against glibc) with a glibc hack to make it somehow run on musl-based system. It’s *not* supported by Alpine and I strongly discourage you from using it.

You can instead use plain Alpine image and simply install openjdk8 package, that includes Nashorn:

```
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk update
apk add openjdk8
```

Oracle JDK is only branded (proprietary) distribution of OpenJDK (that is open-source), the code base is nearly identical. This means that almost all Java applications that runs on Oracle JDK 8 runs also on OpenJDK 8.

Comment: Is there a reason you recommend building own image vs. reusing existing `openjdk:8-alpine` from the [Docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) ?

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov I dunno, I don’t use Docker. The image you’ve linked uses Alpine’s openjdk8 package, so it should be fine too.

Comment: I have temporary solved the problem by installing openjdk8

Comment: Thank you - 2 years after you posted it, this helped a lot